# What states besides Japan have a/the Sibyl System?

Tags: psycho-pass

I'm in the middle of Psycho-Pass Season 1.

What states besides Japan have a (or the?) Sibyl System? There's this part in Episode 13 where 'world' rather than 'Japan' is used. Does the Sibyl System cover the whole world? Does it or do the dominators apply to anyone anywhere even in Antartica or International Waters? Are the police in third world countries using dominators?

I highly doubt Japan is the only place that has a/the Sibyl System because I don't see why the UN would just allow Japan if it disagreed or would not follow Japan if it agreed. It's like [The Walking Dead: I highly doubt it's only the US that's infected.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128625/how-widespread-is-the-infection-in-the-walking-dead) If so, the UN likely would've intervened already (like in world war z iirc).

**If any of these cannot be answered without spoilers, please use** >! and indicate degree of spoilers (or whatever is the site policy for questions like this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, this had to be done with (major) spoiler(s). The spoiler below only to answer your question.

(spoiler for movie)

> Apparently japan is in the only one that operated Sibyl System (or any system alike). This fact shown in the [movie](http://myanimelist.net/anime/21339/Psycho-Pass_Movie).

On side note (this spoiler contains major plot spoiler - proceed with at your own risk),

(spoiler for s2 but not movie)

> The movie also shown the fact that the entire world actually get a dive in governance - anarchy everywhere. Then, only Sibyl System preserve *peace* in Japan. Not to mention how Sibyl System managed to **replace** the entire Japan Diet Member and convinced to measure the Psycho-Pass of the society - as the consequence of Akane's Request in [Season 2](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23281/Psycho-Pass_2).

I hope you'll finish Psycho-Pass and catch up to Season 2 (including the Movie of course).

Comment: ummm thanks hehehe. so whether or not other states besides japan has sibyl/dominators is a spoiler for psycho-pass? thinking about it more, i highly doubt japan is the only place that does that because i don't see why the UN would just allow japan if they disagreed or would not follow japan if they agreed

Comment: i think you could wait until you watch the movie, although it isn't fool-proof. as the nature of psycho-pass believing in some kind of oracle machine is still hard for most people, not to mention their secretive nature on how they actually operates - just like how we can't trust internet for privacy and such. not to mention the main point of psycho-pass is the conflict on accepting the oracle machine.

Comment: Okay fine thanks Tezla hahaha. my questions are not stupid; are they? It's like The Walking Dead: I highly doubt it's only the US that's infected. If so, the UN likely would've intervened already.

Comment: Actually Tezla, just to clarify, is it really the case that the viewers are not supposed to know if or what places outside Japan also use a/the Sibyl? Like, as far as we know Japan (the whole archipelago?) uses Sibyl and then we really don't know about how the world is outside Japan? (Assuming of course the setting really IS Japan... :| )

Comment: `just to clarify, is it really the case that the viewers are not supposed to know if or what places outside Japan also use a/the Sibyl` i think it was left that way to open a hole for new series/movies. did any anime actually tell everything and you start end up bored watching. i don't think whoever behind psycho-pass (not always Urbouchi) will do thing like that.

Comment: 'did any anime actually tell everything and you start end up bored watching.' --> Tezla, honestly, I found the first 10 episodes kind of boring. I think the series would have been better if the ending of episode 11 was given or foreshadowed much earlier. Hence, now that you mention it, I find it kind of inconsistent that PP gives us all these details about these criminals whom I'm guessing have little relevance to the plot later on (don't spoil if they are hahaha)...

Comment: ...PP may have benefited from doing something a little bit like what OUAT or HTGAWM does. Well anyway, hope that answers your question. Thanks

Comment: well, recent anime industry had different approach than their *early* years. story telling isn't the main part sometimes. but it's rather irrelevant to discuss this :) (or review an anime) here.

Comment: Tezla, I finished s1. Does your answer involve season 2? the movie?

Comment: yes, it related. that's why i hope you catch up soon with season 2 and movie. the first spoiler is the movie, the second one is season 2.

Comment: Hahaha thanks. wait are all the answers to my questions really spoilers? Even the ones about Antartica and third world?

Comment: i ended up not yet watching s2 or the movie but i decided to read the spoilers anyway. i don't find them that big of spoilers. are they really? i mean, i figure it's like the 'rosebud' in citizen kane spoiler. doesn't seem like much but when you start to watch citizen kane you realise how much telling what rosebud is is a spoiler. so once i start to watch s2, i will realise how big of spoilers they are?

Comment: Wait for the movie spoiler part...maybe not to do with psycho-pass or even anime specifically but is that really a spoiler? It sounds maybe simply like information not yet revealed, like maybe they just forgot to reveal it, rather than actual spoiler for an important plot point.